# Preventing infinite sound loop after a div is invisible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example image

[image]

I am working on a simple game currently. As for my game, I made a div invisible when another div reaches border of that div. And added a part of sound to that event. But, problem is, it does not work as it should. When first div reach to second div, sound effect is working, but after first div reach to third div, there is a problem — the sound effect of that event (first div to third div) giving a result of infinite loop sound effects. This infinite loop of sound effects has sound of the first event that I explained. How can I prevent this issue?

My code is here,

The event which I talked about is a collision thing; `#character` is my character, `#taskapsa2` is a wall.

```
        function collision6($taskapsa2, $character) {
          var x1 = $taskapsa2.offset().left;
          var y1 = $taskapsa2.offset().top;
          var h1 = $taskapsa2.outerHeight(true);
          var w1 = $taskapsa2.outerWidth(true);
          var b1 = y1 + h1;
          var r1 = x1 + w1;
          var x2 = $character.offset().left;
          var y2 = $character.offset().top;
          var h2 = $character.outerHeight(true);
          var w2 = $character.outerWidth(true);
          var b2 = y2 + h2;
          var r2 = x2 + w2;

          if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return;
     else {
    $("#character").hide();
 var audio22 = new Audio('lost.mp3');
audio22.play();}

        }


    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('#result').text(collision6($('#taskapsa2'), $('#character')));
    }, 200);
```

Here, `.con1` is coin. When character reaches to coin, JS plays my first sound. But after that event (when character touches the wall), my first sound looping infinitely instead (while my second sound doesn't work properly) but I don't want that. I want to play my second sound after that event only once like the first sound.

```
$("#mavikutu").hide();

    function collision7($icon1, $character) {
      var x1 = $icon1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $icon1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $icon1.outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $icon1.outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $character.offset().left;
      var y2 = $character.offset().top;
      var h2 = $character.outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $character.outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return;
 else {$(".icon").hide();
 $("#mavikutu").show();
 var audio11 = new Audio('coinsound.mp3');
audio11.play();

} // COIN SAKLADIM

    }


window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(collision7($('.icon'), $('#character')));
}, 200);
```

You can think the `coinsound.mp3` as first sound, `lost.mp3` as second sound. First sound works well, but after that (when character touches to the wall) it repeats the `coinsound.mp3` infinitely. I don't want that; I want to run `lost.mp3` as second sound *only once*.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You calling `collision7` function every 200  milliseconds and every time getting to `else` clause of `if` - so you playing the sound. Add some flag or class to shown/hidden div - so you can check that your flag is not set yet, play it once and then set the flag. So next time you will not play the sound.

Second solution is to check old state of div (hidden/shown) and new state after calculation - play sound only if the state changed.

Example:

```
$("#mavikutu").hide();

function collision7($icon1, $character) {
      var x1 = $icon1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $icon1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $icon1.outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $icon1.outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $character.offset().left;
      var y2 = $character.offset().top;
      var h2 = $character.outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $character.outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
        return;
      } else {
        if($icon1.is(":visible")) {
          $(".icon").hide();
          $("#mavikutu").show();
          var audio11 = new Audio('coinsound.mp3');
          audio11.play();
        } 
      } // COIN SAKLADIM
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(collision7($('.icon'), $('#character')));
}, 200);
```

Comment: If its not that much, can you give me an example of code? Where is that 200 miliseconds thing on my code? But if it will get you tired, don't bother anyways, thanks! :) Edit : Oh i saw it!

Comment: setInterval(func, 200) - calling func every 200 milliseconds

Comment: But if i wouldnt call it value of 200 ms, how it will understand my collision instantly? Can you help me with some language of coding?

Comment: See example in my answer